# How can I interact with directories in C++?

Tags: c++

Is the C++ language dealing with directories like create, delete, get directory content, search, etc.

Does C++ have an internal library or are there external libraries ?

Is there a recommended library?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Boost](http://www.boost.org/).[Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/) is what you want:

> The Boost.Filesystem library provides facilities to manipulate files and directories, and the paths that identify them.

Answer (score 6):

Libraries that support this:

- [Boost Filesystem](http://www.boost.org/libs/filesystem/)
- [Qt](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/stable/qdir.html)
- [PoCo](http://pocoproject.org/docs/)

---

Boost Filesystem is a library that will in some shape or form most likely end up in a TRn library (Standard Technical Report library sepcification):

> File System.
>
> A standard file system library provides portable facilities to query and manipulate paths, files, and directories. It will enable C++ programmers to perform portable script-like operations from within C++ programs. **The Boost.Filesystem library (which you can download and install individually) was proposed as a candidate for Technical Report 2**. I believe that there's a wide consensus about the necessity of a standard file system library in C++. However, such a library will not be part of C++0x because the committee is now focusing on finalizing the Committee Draft, which leaves little room for adding new libraries. **A file system library will probably ship as a separate TR.**

Answer (score 2):

The QT library also has cross platform support for file and directory manipulation.

See:

- http://qt.nokia.com/
- http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/io.html